# Where to put data consistency logic?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `User` entity, with a `Many-To-One` relationship with `Company` entity, `Many-To-Many` relationship with `Department` entity, and also has a `role` field.

A user `U1` is a manager in the "D" department in the "C" company if they has a `role="manager"`, `company="C"`, `departments=["D", ...]`. But one department can has only one manager, so I need somehow maintain this restriction.

When a new user `U2` is created with `role="manager"`, `company="C"`, `departments=["D", ...]`, I must delete "D" department from the `U1.departments` collection.

What is the best way for maintaining such a data consistency logic (and where to put it, doctrine lc events?)? (I know the logic is quite weird but I can't change it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [Doctrine Entity Listener](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners) is fit for that. I eventually put the data integrity logic in it this way:

**User entity:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"SomeNamespace\UserListener"})
 */
class User
{
 // some irrelevant to the question code here
}
```

**Entity listener for the User entity:**

```
class UserListener
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function reassignManagers(User $user, LifecycleEventArgs $event) {
      // here all the data integrity stuff
    }
}
```